# Android changing the background color for preference fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have set a theme for my application, which includes a blue background...

However, this made my preference fragment blue too. I want to keep the original "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar".

How to do so? thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Add the following code to your PreferenceFragment implementation:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.your_color));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: The text on my screen is very dark in this case. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Six years have passed, 2019 now... Preference fragment styling is still a headache... -_- @Alioo How did you make the text appear white, if you remember?  :P

Comment: I wish, sorry I can't be more help @varun

Comment: @Alioo Oh, thanks for the response! Haha, after 2 days of experimentation and overthinking, I scrapped everything and started afresh. The simple solution was to kick out the `com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.1` support library altogether and just use AppCompat theme styles judiciously, along with AppCompatDelegate for the preference activity!  :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use a style file or in your PreferenceActivity add this

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); // or whatever color value you want
```

Comment: No... it does not work... an error of "null pointer exception" is returned.... and i have a fragment not a activity...

Comment: remove? I use a preference fragment (to suit my application... as I use fragments for my app...) thus I want to keep my preference in a fragment instead of activity....

Comment: no no don't remove, i say just remove fragment for a second and try without it, i just want to test whether it (background color code) works without fragments