# PreferenceFragment background color

Tags: android, background-color, preference

I am using a `PreferenceFragment` (without a `ListView`), but am unable to set the background color, and it seems to be transparent.

How can I set the background color to white with `PreferenceFragment`?

EDIT:
first screenshot: 
[image: image 1]

Overriding onCreateView not work - 
[image: image 2]

Comment: Check my answer [here][1] it should work.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353861/android-changing-the-background-color-for-preference-fragment/17072511#17072511

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This question was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353861/android-changing-the-background-color-for-preference-fragment)

Adding the following code to your PreferenceFragment will let you add a background color, image, etc.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.your_color));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change color only bellow preferences controls? To leave the empty area transparent.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can do something like changing the view's background in the `onViewCreated()` method.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOUR_COLOR));
}
```

Comment: The actual answer in this thread didn't work for me, but this fixed it! :D :D Thanks a lot for the solution :D

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same requirement (Androidx Preference Screen background for settings fragment).

The below code has worked for me. (in themes.xml)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        ...............
       <!-- Add below -->
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/preference</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="preference" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:background">@color/purple_200</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```